# Poisson Distribution. Probability the no. of trees of 35 acres is at least 31?

Tags: probability, statistics, poisson-distribution

The no. of trees for an acre is a poisson random variable with mean 30. Find the probability that the no. of trees for 35 acres is at least 31?

How do I go about gathering this. I know i can get such a distribution for 1 acre via just inserting the values into the poisson distribution function, but what do you do for 35?

Comment: The total number of trees in $35$ acres is at least $31$ or the average number of trees  per acre  in $35$ acres is at least $31$?  The former is extremely close to $1$

Answer (score 0):

The number of trees in 35 acres is also Poisson but with mean $35 \cdot 30$.

This fact can be justified either by the assumptions of a [Poisson scatter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_scatter_theorem) or by noting that the sum of $n$ independent $\text{Poisson}(\lambda)$ random variables is $\text{Poisson}(n\lambda)$.